# FileLock on Android doesn't do anything?

Tags: java, android, locking

I attempt to lock a file on my device's "external" storage (not removable in my case) as it's being written. After I've obtained the lock, I am able to go into a file browser (in another app) and read or delete the file as it's being written. Is there no way to prevent this?

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileNameOut);
lock = fos.getChannel().lock();
outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no way to prevent this?

There is no way to prevent this ... short of rewriting the other application.

The Android platform has a Linux-based kernel, and on Linux / Unix systems file locking is discretionary.  An application will only notice that a file is "locked" if it attempts to acquire a lock on the file for itself.  They typically don't, and if they don't there is nothing you can do about it.

---

> FileLock on Android doesn't do anything?

Not correct.  It does something, but not what you expected.

Read the "Platform Dependencies" section of the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html).